# libfuzzer heap overflow in malloc

Tags: c, testing, fuzzing, libfuzzer

I am trying out my hand at libfuzzer and I am facing 'heap overflow' at malloc.
The code snippet is as follows

```
int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(
    const unsigned char * Data,
    size_t Size
) {
    initialize_state_before_fuzzing();

    size_t charOffset = 0;
    size_t testValueSize = 0;
    size_t arrayLength = 0;
    size_t arrayLength2 = 0;
    const size_t FIXED_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    if (Size == 0)
      return 0;
    uint8_t *testValue_1 = malloc(Size);
    testValueSize = Size;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < testValueSize && charOffset < Size; i++) {
        testValue_1[i] = (uint8_t) Data[charOffset];
        charOffset++;
    }
```

The overflow happens when `Data=""` and `Size = 7`. My question is why does libfuzzer give data that is not equal to the size? How to avoid this?

Also, even if Data is NULL, why does malloc cause heap overflow?

Comment: Please add minimal, complete and verifiable example in your question.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]. When `Data` is the empty string and `Size` is 7, it looks like your loop attempts an out of bounds array access with `Data[charOffset]` as `charOffset` is incremented each time through the loop. When `Data` is `NULL`, `Data[charOffset]` attempts to dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think **the key point** where the error occurred is that you did not check if `Data` is NULL when executing function `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` and without guarantee `sizeof(Data) / sizeof(Data[0]) >= size`.

When you check if `Data` is NULL at execute function `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` before, and the value of size  is suitable, at here such as `Size = 7`, the problem may be disappear.

You can call function `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(Data, Size)` only when `Data` is not equal to NULL and `sizeof(Data) / sizeof(Data[0]) >= size`.

like this:

```
...
...

    if ((Data != NULL) && (sizeof(Data) / sizeof(Data[0])) >= size)
    {
        LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(Data, Size);
    }
    else
    {

          // something else that you want to do
    }
...
...
```

And check if `testValue_1` is NULL that return value by `malloc` in `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` function.

Like this:

```
    uint8_t *testValue_1 = malloc(Size);
    if(testValue_1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("testValue_1 malloc failed, no space\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

If possible, please provide additional information, such as code snippets and error messages